# 'Reset' scoped session bean using Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, session

I have a webservice with a session bean like that;

```
@Scope(value=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, 
       proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
private DocumentModel docModel;
```

I want to maintain the state of all objects inside `DocumentModel` during a process and when it is over reset that object, because I don't want that the sessions keeps all the data related with that object generated during the previous process. Is possible do that in some way different than put a `docModel.reset()` than set all the objects inside it to null?

Thanks